# How to hold data for jar as library with cluster awareness

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jar, cluster-computing

I am creating a library (java jar file ) to provide a solution of a problem. Library is mainly targeted for web application (j2ee application) can be used with spring and other framework.
Targeted j2ee application will be deployed in clustered environment.User will use this library by adding it in application class path.

Library has a dependency of some configuration which is packaged itself in library (jar)  which will be used at run time.
At run time configuration can be modified.

As it is targeted for clustered environment, In case of any modification to configuration , updated configuration must be replicated to all of nodes of clustered environment.

As per my understanding there can be two ways to hold configuration to use at run time (I am not sure correct me if I am wrong)

1.Store configuration in file

2.Store configuration in database

**In first approach (store configuration in file)**
There will a property file in library to hold initial configuration .
At server start up time configuration from property file will be copied to some file (abc.xml) at server physical location.

There will be set of APIs to perform CRUD action in abc.xml file from user home location.
And every time abc.xml file will be used.

In this approach holding data is possible but for clustered environment I am not getting how it will update all the nodes of cluster in case of modification.

**In second appraoch (store configuration in database table)**

While publishing toolkit (jar file) sql table queries also published with jar.
User have to create table using that queries.

There will a property file in library to hold initial configuration .
At server start up time configuration from property file will be copied to database.

There will be set of APIs to perform CRUD action on database.
As there is any modification to configuration all nodes of cluster can updated with latest data using some third party tool (Hazel cast or any thing else.)

In analysis I found Quartz uses database approach to hold its configuration.
So when one download quartz distribution, it also have sql queries to create required tables in database, that will be used by quartz it self.

I want to know what are the standard design pratices to hold configuration in library (jar) form and what are the factor need to be noticed in such cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other solutions as well. Use a cluster aware caching technologies like [EhCache](http://ehcache.org/) or [Apache JCS](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jcs/) or [Hazelcast](http://hazelcast.org/). Use the cache API to retrieve configuration data from the library. You could add in a listener within your library to poll on to the configuration file and update the cache.

If you are planning to use solution 1 which you mentioned, you could set up a listener within your library which listens to the configuration file and updates the server copy whenever there is a change. Similarly for Solution 2 as well but if I were in your similar situation, I would rather use a caching technology for frequently accessed data(configurations). The advantage it would give me is that I would not have to update the configuration in all the nodes because it self replicates.

Comment: Thanks Richie for your answer, Agree there are other solutions but I am looking for a standard design approach for this or what other well known framework (other than quartz) do in this case.Regarding updating cache,as it is self replicate will make it easy for me, but to persist configuration in file or DB still open question.

Comment: store in properties file and load properties to cache - doesn't it sound more like an enterprise way?

Comment: I selected data based approach to persist configuration and hazel cast to share cache among nodes of cluster environment.